# VBA execution being passed to module while deleting a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing a strange issue. Sorry if its too dumb or something obvious i missed.

I have userform termination sub. While debugging i saw the control was being passed to another module in the workbook called "Numtowords" when i am trying to delete a temp worksheet while userform termination. I am nowhere invoking the module. So not sure why such behavior. Below are screens that show as soon as i press F8 when the control is at Worksheet ("Agent_info_temp").Delete the control reaches the module numtowords.

Please help why this is happening. I searched a lot but may be my phrasing is incorrect. If cant be resolved can i somehow stop the module call??
[image: Step 1:]

then this happens

[image: Step 2:]

Comment: Is `NumToWords` referencing any cells on the deleted sheet? I suspect all you need to do is set calculation to manual.  That's if you're even worried about it - does it really matter if cells on the deleting sheet are evaluating when you delete it?

Comment: No i dont want to check the content of the sheet being deleted. This is just a sanity cleanup which i am doing each time the user form closes. I tried below code for setting up the calculation to manual. still its happening - "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Agent_info_Temp").EnableCalculation = False"

Comment: Try `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual|xlCalculationAutomatic`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely Agent_Info_Temp is invoking NumToWords as a formula in one of its columns.  When you Set wsSheet, the sheet goes through its calculation procedure.  If NumToWords is there, it gets invoked and you see it in the debug stream.

I think you can turn Automatic ReCalc off (in VBA), then go through the deletion step.

Comment: Yea.. this worked. I guess thats what Comintern was also referring. thanks to both. appreciate your quick help. But strange thing is there was no reference of he module in that sheet Still it was being invoked.